# How do I get a data associated with a button pressed?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-button

When a user selects an item to delete, I open an alertDialog to make sure he wants to delete it. When I get the onClick for BUTTON_POSITIVE I need to get the file name to delete. This was known before opening the alertDialog. I tried using setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", msg) and set the file name in the message but it is not clear to me where do I get the message? Can someone clarify or propose a better implementation?

Here's the code that runs after clicking the delete button:

```
public void OnClick(View v)
{
    Button b = (Button)v;
    CharSequence cs = b.getText();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(cs.toString());

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.arg1 = id;

    AlertDialog deleteAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    deleteAlert.setTitle("Trigger Remove Alert");
    deleteAlert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove this trigger?");
    deleteAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", msg);
    deleteAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {               
    //remove Trigger
        //boolean b = RemoveTriggerPOI(aid, id);
    }
    });
    deleteAlert.setButton2("No", new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //...
    }
    });
    deleteAlert.show();



}
```

Comment: its easy, show us the code so we can suggest what to do

Comment: are **cs** and **id** the values you want to access when a button on dialog is clicked?

Comment: yes, just use id in your click's listener as i've mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define your `id` or `cs` as:

```
final int id = Integer.parseInt(cs.toString());
final CharSequence cs = b.getText();
```

Now simply use `cs` and `id` inside the dialog button's *onClick* listener:

```
 deleteAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {               
       //remove Trigger
       //boolean b = RemoveTriggerPOI(aid, id);

       //SIMPLY USE id OR cs HERE. IT SHOULD WORK
    }
    });
```

Comment: I tried but I get the following error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable id inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: Great, thanks. What's the issue with MSG. How one can get it?

Comment: just skip/remove that line. it doesnt apply in your case :)